# Finding a special row in a data frame in Rcpp ( filtering in Rcpp corresponding to filter() in R)

Tags: rcpp

I am very new in Rcpp. Assume we have two data frames: edge and ref, edge consists of three columns: time, sender, receiver. ref consists of three columns sender, receiver and teller. teller shows the indices of rows which is from 1 to nrow(ref). You can see an example below. I want to go through each row of "edge" and find which row of the "ref" is the same as that. Let's say you go through edge and ref and find that the index of that row in ref is 10.  Then I create a data frame, say "dat", with two columns: time and status. Then I replace the corresponding value in dat$status with one. That is, dat$status[10]<- 1. I wrote the code in R as follows:

```
cdata <- lapply(2:nrow(edge), function(z) {
welke <- filter(ref, sender == edge[z, "sender"], receiver == edge[z, "receiver"])$teller
dat <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(ref), ncol = 2) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  set_colnames(c("time","status"))
dat$status[welke] <- 1

return(dat)
}) %>%
 dplyr::bind_rows()
```

[image: Example: edge and ref]

I do not know how can I translate into Rcpp.

Comment: You are probably better off using `data.table` (or base R or `dplyr`).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  there is also lapply that I want to replace it with for loop in Rcpp.